# Problem with my HDD

Tags: hard-drive

This is my smartctl error log

````
Error 942 [1] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 29285 hours (1220 days + 5 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 51 00 00 00 00 43 00 45 fa 00 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x430045fa = 1124091386

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 28 00 45 90 e0 00     00:00:56.952  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 27 00 45 90 e0 00     00:00:56.944  READ DMA EXT
  35 00 00 00 08 00 24 e1 00 ee 28 e0 00     00:00:56.943  WRITE DMA EXT
  35 00 00 00 08 00 16 09 00 62 70 e0 00     00:00:56.943  WRITE DMA EXT
  35 00 00 00 08 00 00 12 00 01 e0 e0 00     00:00:56.942  WRITE DMA EXT

Error 941 [0] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 29285 hours (1220 days + 5 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 51 00 00 00 00 43 00 45 fa 00 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x430045fa = 1124091386

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 2e 00 45 90 e0 00     00:00:55.382  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 2d 00 45 90 e0 00     00:00:55.370  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 2c 00 45 90 e0 00     00:00:55.369  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 2b 00 45 90 e0 00     00:00:55.368  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 2a 00 45 90 e0 00     00:00:55.367  READ DMA EXT

Error 940 [19] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 29285 hours (1220 days + 5 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 51 00 00 00 00 43 00 45 fa 00 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x430045fa = 1124091386

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 28 00 45 90 e0 00     00:00:53.819  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 27 00 45 90 e0 00     00:00:53.810  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 27 00 45 90 e0 00     00:00:53.799  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 45 00 45 90 e0 00     00:00:53.618  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 44 00 45 90 e0 00     00:00:53.559  READ DMA EXT

Error 939 [18] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 29285 hours (1220 days + 5 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 51 00 00 00 00 43 00 45 fa 00 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x430045fa = 1124091386

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 28 00 45 90 e0 00     00:00:52.273  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 27 00 45 90 e0 00     00:00:52.263  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 45 00 45 90 e0 00     00:00:52.082  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 44 00 45 90 e0 00     00:00:52.023  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 28 00 45 90 e0 00     00:00:50.724  READ DMA EXT

Error 938 [17] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 29285 hours (1220 days + 5 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 51 00 00 00 00 43 00 45 fa 00 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x430045fa = 1124091386

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 28 00 45 90 e0 00     00:00:50.724  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 27 00 45 90 e0 00     00:00:50.724  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 01 00 00 27 00 45 88 e0 00     00:00:50.704  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 e9 00 64 d8 e0 00     00:00:50.698  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 67 00 64 48 e0 00     00:00:50.683  READ DMA EXT

Error 937 [16] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 29285 hours (1220 days + 5 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 51 00 00 00 00 43 00 45 fa 00 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x430045fa = 1124091386

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  25 20 20 00 7f 00 00 40 00 45 07 e0 00     00:00:20.458  READ DMA EXT
  25 20 20 00 7f 00 00 3f 00 45 88 e0 00     00:00:20.395  READ DMA EXT
  25 20 20 00 7f 00 00 40 00 45 07 e0 00     00:00:19.145  READ DMA EXT
  25 20 20 00 7f 00 00 3f 00 45 88 e0 00     00:00:19.083  READ DMA EXT
  25 20 20 00 7f 00 00 28 00 45 07 e0 00     00:00:17.797  READ DMA EXT

Error 936 [15] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 29285 hours (1220 days + 5 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 51 00 00 00 00 43 00 45 fa 00 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x430045fa = 1124091386

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  25 20 20 00 7f 00 00 40 00 45 07 e0 00     00:00:19.145  READ DMA EXT
  25 20 20 00 7f 00 00 3f 00 45 88 e0 00     00:00:19.083  READ DMA EXT
  25 20 20 00 7f 00 00 28 00 45 07 e0 00     00:00:17.797  READ DMA EXT
  25 20 20 00 7f 00 00 27 00 45 88 e0 00     00:00:17.785  READ DMA EXT
  25 20 20 00 02 00 04 7a 00 76 a4 e0 00     00:00:17.769  READ DMA EXT

Error 935 [14] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 29285 hours (1220 days + 5 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 51 00 00 00 00 43 00 45 fa 00 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x430045fa = 1124091386

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  25 20 20 00 7f 00 00 28 00 45 07 e0 00     00:00:17.797  READ DMA EXT
  25 20 20 00 7f 00 00 27 00 45 88 e0 00     00:00:17.785  READ DMA EXT
  25 20 20 00 02 00 04 7a 00 76 a4 e0 00     00:00:17.769  READ DMA EXT
  25 20 20 00 10 00 00 5a 00 03 60 e0 00     00:00:17.768  READ DMA EXT
  25 20 20 00 10 00 00 5a 00 03 50 e0 00     00:00:17.760  READ DMA EXT

Error 934 [13] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 29285 hours (1220 days + 5 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 51 00 00 00 00 43 00 45 fa 00 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x430045fa = 1124091386

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 28 00 45 90 e0 00     00:08:02.356  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 27 00 45 90 e0 00     00:08:02.325  READ DMA EXT
  35 00 00 00 08 00 00 ea 00 64 38 e0 00     00:08:02.325  WRITE DMA EXT
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 45 00 45 90 e0 00     00:08:02.145  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 44 00 45 90 e0 00     00:08:02.035  READ DMA EXT

Error 933 [12] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 29285 hours (1220 days + 5 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 51 00 00 00 00 43 00 45 fa 00 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x430045fa = 1124091386

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 28 00 45 90 e0 00     00:08:00.738  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 27 00 45 90 e0 00     00:08:00.730  READ DMA EXT
  35 00 00 00 03 00 03 66 00 b9 78 e0 00     00:08:00.728  WRITE DMA EXT
  35 00 00 00 08 00 00 0c 00 72 f8 e0 00     00:08:00.728  WRITE DMA EXT
  35 00 00 00 08 00 00 05 00 5f c8 e0 00     00:08:00.728  WRITE DMA EXT

Error 932 [11] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 29285 hours (1220 days + 5 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 51 00 00 00 00 43 00 45 fa 00 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x430045fa = 1124091386

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 28 00 45 90 e0 00     00:07:59.141  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 27 00 45 90 e0 00     00:07:59.131  READ DMA EXT
  35 00 00 00 08 00 00 05 00 5f d8 e0 00     00:07:59.131  WRITE DMA EXT
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 45 00 45 90 e0 00     00:07:58.950  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 44 00 45 90 e0 00     00:07:58.892  READ DMA EXT

Error 931 [10] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 29285 hours (1220 days + 5 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 51 00 00 00 00 43 00 45 fa 00 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x430045fa = 1124091386

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 28 00 45 90 e0 00     00:07:57.615  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 27 00 45 90 e0 00     00:07:57.607  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 45 00 45 90 e0 00     00:07:57.424  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 44 00 45 90 e0 00     00:07:57.366  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 28 00 45 90 e0 00     00:07:56.069  READ DMA EXT

Error 930 [9] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 29285 hours (1220 days + 5 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 51 00 00 00 00 43 00 45 fa 00 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x430045fa = 1124091386

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 28 00 45 90 e0 00     00:07:56.069  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 27 00 45 90 e0 00     00:07:56.059  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 45 00 45 90 e0 00     00:07:55.878  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 44 00 45 90 e0 00     00:07:55.819  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 28 00 45 90 e0 00     00:07:54.523  READ DMA EXT

Error 929 [8] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 29285 hours (1220 days + 5 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 51 00 00 00 00 43 00 45 fa 00 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x430045fa = 1124091386

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 28 00 45 90 e0 00     00:07:54.523  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 27 00 45 90 e0 00     00:07:54.514  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 49 00 45 90 e0 00     00:07:54.336  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 48 00 45 90 e0 00     00:07:54.245  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 47 00 45 90 e0 00     00:07:54.245  READ DMA EXT

Error 928 [7] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 29285 hours (1220 days + 5 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 51 00 00 00 00 43 00 45 fa 00 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x430045fa = 1124091386

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 28 00 45 90 e0 00     00:07:52.946  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 27 00 45 90 e0 00     00:07:52.939  READ DMA EXT
  35 00 00 00 08 00 00 28 00 63 28 e0 00     00:07:52.938  WRITE DMA EXT
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 44 00 45 90 e0 00     00:07:52.879  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 34 00 45 90 e0 00     00:07:51.596  READ DMA EXT

Error 927 [6] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 29285 hours (1220 days + 5 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 51 00 00 00 00 43 00 45 fa 00 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x430045fa = 1124091386

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 34 00 45 90 e0 00     00:07:51.596  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 33 00 45 90 e0 00     00:07:51.589  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 32 00 45 90 e0 00     00:07:51.588  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 31 00 45 90 e0 00     00:07:51.588  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 30 00 45 90 e0 00     00:07:51.587  READ DMA EXT

Error 926 [5] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 29285 hours (1220 days + 5 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 51 00 00 00 00 43 00 45 fa 00 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x430045fa = 1124091386

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  25 00 00 00 80 00 00 43 00 45 90 e0 00     00:07:29.652  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 80 00 00 43 00 45 90 e0 00     00:07:28.350  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 43 00 45 90 e0 00     00:07:27.038  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 43 00 45 90 e0 00     00:07:25.752  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 44 00 45 90 e0 00     00:07:25.695  READ DMA EXT

Error 925 [4] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 29285 hours (1220 days + 5 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 51 00 00 00 00 43 00 45 fa 00 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x430045fa = 1124091386

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  25 00 00 00 80 00 00 43 00 45 90 e0 00     00:07:28.350  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 43 00 45 90 e0 00     00:07:27.038  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 43 00 45 90 e0 00     00:07:25.752  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 44 00 45 90 e0 00     00:07:25.695  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 43 00 45 90 e0 00     00:07:24.419  READ DMA EXT

Error 924 [3] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 29285 hours (1220 days + 5 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 51 00 00 00 00 43 00 45 fa 00 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x430045fa = 1124091386

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 43 00 45 90 e0 00     00:07:27.038  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 43 00 45 90 e0 00     00:07:25.752  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 44 00 45 90 e0 00     00:07:25.695  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 43 00 45 90 e0 00     00:07:24.419  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 44 00 45 90 e0 00     00:07:24.357  READ DMA EXT

Error 923 [2] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 29285 hours (1220 days + 5 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 51 00 00 00 00 43 00 45 fa 00 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x430045fa = 1124091386

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 43 00 45 90 e0 00     00:07:25.752  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 44 00 45 90 e0 00     00:07:25.695  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 43 00 45 90 e0 00     00:07:24.419  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 44 00 45 90 e0 00     00:07:24.357  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 01 00 00 00 43 00 45 90 e0 00     00:07:23.099  READ DMA EXT```
````

Comment: Please edit your post and add the actual problem you have. The posts holds currently only a description of the current state - but no question.